# pulling from upstream creates duplicate commits

Tags: git, github

i have two repos. the "upstream" is the base version, and the "origin" is a fork with modifications. that is, changes to "upstream" should be pushed to "origin", but changes to "origin" should not be pushed to "upstream".

the problem now is that from "origin", when I do `git pull upstream master`, i always get a merge conflict. these conflicts always are always the same 3 commits in "upstream"'s past that I have already fixed. if i then do `git rebase`, i have to resolve these merge conflicts again, so i have stopped doing that. if i then push these changes to github, i see the same 3 commits being added over and over again on every push, creating a lot of duplicates in the commit history, making it very ugly.

how do i solve this? am i approaching this problem wrong? is there a better way?

Comment: Have you pushed rebased commits that have already been pushed before? If so, there's your problem.

Comment: How do I solve this? What are the right commands?

Comment: Can you explain what exactly you are rebasing? I.e. what rebase command are you using **exactly** and with the intention of doing what **exactly**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i no longer rebase anything and i no longer have any issues. whatever.